# How to Search for a number and replace it with other number

Tags: grep

I have a file server.xml with below line-

```
Server port="8007" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"
```

I want to search for `8007` and replace it with other number eg.: `8010`.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please add sample xml file and your desired output for that sample to your question.

Comment: @user6378152 why do you think `grep` is suitable for this task?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
sed 's/8007/8010/g' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

To make replacements you can use sed. I suppose that the new "port" is stored in a variable. As a result both solutions bellow works ok with GNU Sed:

```
$ a=$'Server port="8007" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"';echo "$a"
Server port="8007" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"

$ newport="8010"
$ sed -r "s/([0-9]+)/$newport/g" <<<"$a"
Server port="8010" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"

# Alternative:
$ sed -r 's/(port=")(.*)(" .*)/\1'"$newport"'\3/g' <<<"$a"
```

`sed -r` (or `sed -E`) enables extended regex groups.
If you need to apply replacements in-place (on the file) you need to use also `-i` switch in sed (`sed -r -i.bak "...."`)